# problem with migrating database on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dbmigrate

I got an error when migrating my database on heroku for my new rails app
here's the error I got

```
rails aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:377:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:12:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:191:in `spec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:950:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:136:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:328:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:27:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
/app/app/models/shop.rb:1:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:374:in `block in require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:352:in `require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:46:in `block in require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:45:in `require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:506:in `load_missing_constant'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `block in load_missing_constant'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:57:in `load_missing_constant'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:193:in `const_missing'
/app/config/initializers/shopify_app.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/shopify_app-8.3.2/lib/shopify_app/configuration.rb:71:in `configure'
/app/config/initializers/shopify_app.rb:1:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:281:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:281:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:7:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
/app/bin/rails:11:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Gem::LoadError: sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:377:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:12:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:191:in `spec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:950:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:136:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:328:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:27:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
/app/app/models/shop.rb:1:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:374:in `block in require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:352:in `require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:46:in `block in require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:45:in `require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:506:in `load_missing_constant'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `block in load_missing_constant'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:57:in `load_missing_constant'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:193:in `const_missing'
/app/config/initializers/shopify_app.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/shopify_app-8.3.2/lib/shopify_app/configuration.rb:71:in `configure'
/app/config/initializers/shopify_app.rb:1:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:281:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:281:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:7:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
/app/bin/rails:11:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

knowing that I'm still beginner with Rails, and to get sqlite3 work with heroku I have to move it inside of development and test group inside my gemfile.

and here's my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Rails Engine for building Shopify Apps.
gem 'shopify_app'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

knowing that I'm still beginner with Rails, and to get sqlite3 work with heroku I have to move it inside of development and test group inside my gemfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me when i started with heroku and rails. I think the problem is that you deployed your app before putting the pg gem in production group and now for some reason even if added the gem you still having the problem.

**Possible solution:**

Delete your Gemfile.lock and run

```
bundle install --without=production
```

Delete the app you deployed on heroku and deploy a new one with the new gemfile.lock.

**My solution:**

I deleted my rails app and created new one, it wasn't a problem since i was just starting the project but i learned that you have to configure your gemfile and your app in general before starting to code and deploy, this is the correct way to go.

Check the first chapter from this tutorial for a correct configuration before deploying to heroku: https://www.railstutorial.org

Answer (score 1):

You need to add pg gem for production. set heroku environment to production. sqlite3 is not supported by heroku.

Comment: then you need to check the environment of your heroku app.